# CUDA ILP, instruction fetch, pipelining and branching

Tags: cuda

I am writing a volumetric ray casting algorithm on CUDA Kepler GTX680. The algorithm is register intensive, which leads to either high register spilling or 50% of the maximum occupancy. The recommended way to improve throughput is to order the instructions to support instruction level parallelism.

To achieve maximum throughput of the architecture, various pipelines have to be kept busy. The arithmetic units have a pipe length of cca. 22 instructions, therefore to achieve their full throughput a new arithmetic operation has to be scheduled at each clock cycle. I expect that swapping warps (deactivating one warp because of its unsatisfied data dependencies and activating another warp which is ready to run) does not touch the arithmetic unit pipeline. I assume therefore, that the CUDA architecture effectively hides some of the instruction dependencies by swapping multiple warps the same way it hides memory latency. Is this assumption correct?

Is the instruction fetch & decoding pipelined? How long is the pipeline? I suppose the instruction pipeline is flushed in case the current warp is swapped out because of unsatisfied data dependency, therefore swapping warps does not come completely for free, right? How does the branching influence instruction processing? I suppose the branching instruction has to stall the instruction pipeline until the branching condition is evaluated, which seems to make predicated evaluation cheaper than branching. Is that so?

How big is the instruction cache for the Kepler GK104/110 architecture and how is it organized? May it be that for a complex kernel the speed of instruction fetching may be the bottleneck?

I would be thankful for any reference that may shed light onto any of the areas I mentioned. NVidia produced plenty of PowerPoint bullet point presentations, but those are only useful as a complement to an oral presentation.

Comment: NVidia also produces the CUDA C Best Practices Guide and Parallel Thread Execution ISA Version 3.1. Have you located those?

Answer (score 3):

It's best to ask one question per question.

> I assume therefore, that the CUDA architecture effectively hides some of the instruction dependencies by swapping multiple warps the same way it hides memory latency. Is this assumption correct?

Yes, the principal mechanism of the machine to hide latency of any type is by having multiple warps that are ready to execute, whether from the same or different blocks.

> therefore swapping warps does not come completely for free, right? (collapsing multiple questions into this one)

No, swapping warps is zero cost.  The first point (latency hiding) depends on this.  From the C programming guide [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#hardware-multithreading):

> The execution context (program counters, registers, etc) for each warp processed by a multiprocessor is maintained on-chip during the entire lifetime of the warp. Therefore, switching from one execution context to another has no cost, and at every instruction issue time, a warp scheduler selects a warp that has threads ready to execute its next instruction (the active threads of the warp) and issues the instruction to those threads.

For general architectural understanding, I would recommend the Fermi [whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_86775.html), the Kepler GK104 (GTX680) [whitepaper](http://international.download.nvidia.com/webassets/en_US/pdf/GeForce-GTX-680-Whitepaper-FINAL.pdf), and the Kepler GK110 [whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf).